# Zentyal/Ubuntu SIP module doesn't stay unloaded

Tags: ubuntu, sip, modprobe

We are using Zentyal 3.1 (Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS - kernel version: 3.2.0.38-generic) as proxy/firewall for our location.
At the moment the firewall rules are set to allow all, however sip packets are still dropped.
This is caused by the module nf_conntrack_sip.

When I manually unload the module + the module nf_nat_sip everything works as expected.
The command I used for unloading is either (both work):

```
    rmmod nf_nat_sip
    rmmod nf_conntrack_sip
```

or

```
    modprobe -r nf_nat_sip
    modprobe -r nf_conntrack_sip
```

After a reboot ofcourse these modules are loaded again, so I added following lines to /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf

```
    blacklist nf_nat_sip
    blacklist nf_conntrack_sip
```

But this didn't prevent the modules from loading. I even created a new file,  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-custom.conf with the same two lines (and a blank new line), but the modules still get loaded at boot.

Then I tried a script that unloads the modules in upstart after the network devices come up, and that works. But after some time the modules do get loaded again by some unknown trigger.

I want these modules unloaded permanently, but kinda clueless atm on any other solutions.

Comment: Ever find an answer to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for me

In: /etc/zentyal/firewall.conf
Remove from iptables_modules = nf_conntrack_sip, nf_nat_sip

Restart Zentyal